# Evolution Calender: search over the whole year... or longer

Tags: calendar, evolution

I am quite satisfied with the [Evolution Mail and Calendar](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/index.html.en#calendar) in my xubuntu computer. However, I am missing a feature: a search over the whole year, or even better, over the whole calendar.

For example, if I want to search for the deadlines to renew or cancel subscriptions, I would search "subscription" in the calendar. Sadly, that works only for the current selected month. I do not know, whether I am missing something or the feature is not present. So my question is following:

Is it possible to search the calendar for appointments in a whole year (or longer!)? Or maybe I should ask: Can I have a whole year view to search in it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Show Active Appointments`** that's the solution! You can choose it in `Show` options (See picture). Then you will see a list of **all future appointments** in the selected calender.

[image]

Strangely enough, the option `Any Category` shows **only** the appointments in the chosen time window (i.e., week or month) but **not all** of them.